# What does $P(X>7|X>5)=P(X>2)$ means? in an exponential distribution

Tags: conditional-probability

What does $P(X>7|X>5)=P(X>2)$  mean in an exponential distribution?

I know that the parameter for the distribution is $\lambda = 4$, but how can I verify that $$ P(X>7|X>5)=P(X>2)? $$ I only need to know how to write it as integral notation, but this conditional does not seem to be as I usually interpret it to be, meaning $$ P(X>5 \ and \ X>7)/P(X>5)$$ that's why my question. Any help?

Comment: Hint:  $P(X> 5\,\text {and}\,X>7)=P(X>7)$.

Comment: _this condicional not seems to be ... $ P(X>5 \ and \ X>7)/P(X>5)$_. Why do you think that?

Comment: @lulu you are right thanks! I see it now

Comment: @Miguel I see it now, thanks

Comment: you could do it as 
$$ \frac {  \int_7^\infty e^{-\lambda t}dt}{  \int_5^\infty e^{-\lambda t}dt}  $$

Comment: $P(X>s+t \mid X>s)=P(X>t)$ for all non-negative $s,t$ is called *memorylessness*